# Why $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/23\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \cong \mathbb{F}_{23}/(x^3-x-1)$ where $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This a step in my notes which I can't seem to understand clearly.  Why $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/23\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \cong \mathbb{F}_{23}/(x^3-x-1)$ where $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$? I see that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $f(x)=x^3-x-1$ but why does this isomorphism hold?

Comment: In general, if $\;F\;$ is a field and $\;\alpha\;$ is a root of some non-zero irreducible polynomial $\;f(x)\in F[x]\;$ then $\;F(\alpha)=F[\alpha]\cong F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-x-1)$ for $\alpha$ being a root of $x^3-x-1=0$.